# Manipulate keys / items from dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am finding it difficult to manipulate keys and items inside of dictionaries within lists. I want to obtain in a variable, for instance, the first indexed item in the first indexed key in all of the dictionaries within a list:

```
Dict = [{"top": 1, "bottom": "a", "left": "b"}, {"top": 2, "bottom": "c", "left": "d"}, {"top": 3, "bottom": "e", "left": "sdfasda"}, {"top": 4, "bottom": "f", "left": "g"}]
```

Output required:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] *#All part of the key "top"*
```

or

```
[a, c, e, f] *#All part of the key "bottom"*
```

depending on which key i am needing.

I would have thought:

```
for x in Dict:
    print(x("top"))
```

Help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Accessing a value in a dictionary is done using `[key]`, not `(key)`. So `print(x["top"])` instead of `print(x("top"))`.

Comment: Apologies my mistake, even so, i get a TypeError: string indices must be integers everytime..

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary values are obtained by the index operator `[key]`, not `(key)`. The last one is used for invoking callables' calls.

```
[x["top"] for x in Dict]
```

would do.

Comment: when i call this as a variable, all i get is a TypeError: string indices must be integers.. Must be something i am doing wrong.

Comment: @ChrisJamieson what happens when you put this inside a print?

Comment: @ChrisJamieson what happens when you put this inside a print?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the required list using list compressions:

```
listTop = [i['top'] for i in Dict]
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Doing this, you will iterate over all dicts inside the Dict List. After that, you take the 'top' value of each one, returning it.

To print it: `[print(i) for i in listTop]`